# Regular expression conditional with JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a regular expression to match sentences like:

1: `99.99.99`

2: `99.99.99,99`

The comma is optional and if given it must have 1 or 2 digits after it. I have this regex which matches the first sentence, but doesn't matches the second:

`^(?:[0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}(,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

**Better exp:**

```
(,[0-9]{1,2})?
```

`[0-9]{1,2}`       any numbers upto limit 2
`(,?[0-9]{1,2})?`  this entire group upto limit 1

Comment: Won't that allow them to add 1 or 2 extra numbers on the end without the comma?

Comment: @M21B8 you're right, I'm still missing the point.  Let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}(,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

(untested, written off the top of my head)

edit: had a random $ in the middle

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/zL5gR6)

Regular  expression:

```
^               the beginning of the string
(?:             group, but do not capture (2 times):
 [0-9]{1,2}     any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1 and 2 times)
 \.             '.'
){2}            end of grouping
 [0-9]{1,2}     any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1 and 2 times)
 (?:            group, but do not capture (optional)
   ,            ','
   [0-9]{1,2}   any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1 and 2 times)
 )?             end of grouping
$               before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```